# Is there away to valid the true whatsapp contact in html form?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an HTML form where user puts his or her whatsapp number but others users always put invalid whatsapp contacts, so I want to valid validate a phone number to know whether it is on whatsapp or not before the form submission.
How is this possible?

I made research severally on Google but failed.

I tried to do research but all failed

Comment: You are looking for OTP (one time password) using WhatsApp API. You need to use their apis to send a message containing a sort of 2FA code to the given number that you will verify in your registration form for matching. There are surely third party services that factors that operation as a service. Anyway using OTP as keyword will probably open a new window to the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.